# Action Performed when Button Clicked n Times

Tags: android, listener, stack-overflow, onclicklistener

```
public void boss(final Boss boss) {
    forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boss.setHp(boss.getHp() - 1);
            log("" + boss.getHp());
        }
    });
    if(boss.getHp() > 0){
        boss(boss);
    }
}
```

So, in the above code, I am trying to have bossHp reduce by 1 every time forward is clicked.  There is a stackoverflow error with the code.  (It is just calling boss() in an infinite loop.)  How can I have it keep reducing bossHp by 1 every time the user clicks forward, and then stop when bossHp <= 0?

Note: Button forward is used elsewhere, too.

Thanks!

**EDIT:  Sorry about that typo earlier! the code shown is now the correct code. Any ideas? Thanks!**

CLARIFICATION:

What I want to have happen, is it checks bossHp every time Button forward is clicked UNTIL bossHp <= 0. At which point I want to exit the method, but not before then

Comment: Are you seeing the infinite loop in the click handler or the boss function itself?  Neither have a direct infinite loop, but its possible boss.getHp, boss.setHp, or bossCombat do.  We'd need the code for them to check though.

Comment: This code fragment is good. But I believe that you call `boss()` in `bossCombat(boss)` which cause inf loop

Comment: post code for `bossCombat()`

Comment: In most cases `setOnClickListener(listener)` should be called only one time.

Comment: Aggree with @AudriusK you would need to post the stack trace for us to be sure.  If you post list the top 10 lines of the stack trace that would most likely be enough.... We/You need to look for a repeating pattern in the stack trace.

Comment: oops im sorry i had a typo in the code. (simplified for posting.) there is no bossCombat() method. its just boss().  (i know what the problem is...i just do not know how to fix it.)

Comment: Your method is recursive (it calls itself) and there is no reachable base-case.

Comment: yes, i know what the problem. what i am looking for is a solution

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Also you don't have to pass boss as function parameter. You can keep that object as field in your class.

```
public void boss(final Boss boss) {
    forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(boss.getHp() > 0){
                boss.setHp(boss.getHp() - 1);
                log("" + boss.getHp());
            } else {
                //boss is dead
            }
        }
    });
}
```