# Staying in a method until a button is clicked so many times

Tags: android, stack-overflow, infinite-loop, onclicklistener

I am trying to have the number reduce by 10 every time myButton is clicked.  Then when the button is less than or equal to 0, I want the method to finish.  I only want the number to be reduced by 10 if the button is actually clicked.

Right now, there is an infinite loop that causes a stack overflow error.  (myMethod keeps calling itself.)  How can i stay in the method until number is less than or equal to 0?  For example, if number = 95, I want to stay in the method until I click myButton 10 times.  Just to be clear, I am aware of what the problem is...I am trying to find a way to fix it.

```
public void myMethod(final int number) {
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            number -= 10;
        }
    });
    if(number > 0){
        myMethod(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand the need to do that..can u explain what do u want?

Comment: Why do you want it to stay in the method. Wouldn't it be better to just have the callback called each time the button is clicked and reduce the number by 10, and then when it is 0 or below do whatever you want to do then?

Comment: I am actually using the button elsewhere. the only time this button behaves this way is in this particular method

Comment: make the button disabled or invisible if the condition if(number > 0) fails

Comment: the button never goes away. it just changes its image and has a different functionality

Comment: I think you need to rethink your design. I'm sure you'll be able to achieve what you want without holding up the UI thread and likely getting ANR dialogs.

Comment: You should not create multiple entries for the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652114/action-performed-when-button-clicked-n-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how you program on an event driven OS.  If you really don't want anything else to work until they click the button 10 times, you need to have all the other functionality in your app check a flag to see if its allowed.  Then the onClick function sets that flag to true when number == 0.  You never hold up the main thread for any reason-  doing so will cause your app to become completely unresponsive, and Android will kill the app as having crashed after a few seconds.

Comment: i do want other stuff within the method to work. i have 6 buttons, and once this method is entered, all 6 of the buttons do different things than they used to. then when the method is exited, i want them to resume their normal jobs

Comment: You need to use a state flag and check what mode the buttons are in in their handlers.  You cannot make a method hold up indefinitely like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your onCreate:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(number > 0)
           number -= 10;
        else
           whateveryouwant();
    }
});
```

You just need to set your listener once.

In your case you are setting the listener an infinite amount of time because number is always greater than 0.

Comment: i want the button to do an unrelated job and to change only during the time it is in that particular method

Comment: And? What is the problem?